# How to get the position of a button on the screen in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

JS can get the x, y of button in document

BrowserWindow.getPosition () can get the position of the window

But the windows have titlebars and menu can't know their height

Comment: This may depend a little on your OS requirements. Could you [edit] those *into* your question, maybe even add another tag if appropiate.